# styles imported with css-loader not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, bootstrap-4

Building a react 16.4.0 app with bootstrap 4.1.1.

I'm using css-loader with webpack to create custom stylesheets for each component in my app.

My custom styles don't do anything.  I thought maybe it was a matter of the bootstrap styles having more points, but even when I add an element that is outside of any bootstrap element, my styles don't take any effect.

Basic example:

Sidebar.js component:

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Sidebar.css';

const sidebar = (props) =>  {
    console.log('classes.red:', classes.red);
    return (
        <div>
            <h3 className={classes.other}>Testing Stylesheet</h3>
            <nav className="col-sm-3 col-md-2 hidded-xs-down sidebar" id={classes.red}>
                <ul className="nav flex-column">
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <a className="nav-link active" href="#">
                            FF1493
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <a className="nav-link active" href="#">
                            FF4500
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    )
}

export default sidebar;
```

Here's the super-simple stylesheet:

```
#red {
    background-color: rgba(214, 21, 21, 0.842)
}

.other {
    color: green;
}
```

In the Sidebar.js you can see where I'm console.logging the imported 'red' style.  Here's what logs in the browser's console: `classes.red: Sidebar__red__2-sUP`  <-- It's bringing in the unique identifier as it should.

For those who'll wanna know, here's my webpack.config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

const SRC_DIR = path.join(__dirname, '/client/src');
const DIST_DIR = path.join(__dirname, '/client/dist');

module.exports = {
    entry: `${SRC_DIR}/index.jsx`,
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/dist'),
      filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?/,
          include: SRC_DIR,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
            plugins: ['syntax-dynamic-import'],
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
            Object.assign(
              {
                fallback: {
                  loader: require.resolve('style-loader'),
                  options: {
                    hmr: false,
                  },
                },
                use: [
                  {
                    loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                    options: {
                      importLoaders: 1,
                      minimize: true,
                      // sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
                      modules: true,
                      localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
                    },
                  },
                  {
                    loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                    options: {
                      // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
                      // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
                      ident: 'postcss',
                      plugins: () => [
                        require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                        autoprefixer({
                          browsers: [
                            '>1%',
                            'last 4 versions',
                            'Firefox ESR',
                            'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                          ],
                          flexbox: 'no-2009',
                        }),
                      ],
                    },
                  },
                ],
              },
              // extractTextPluginOptions
            )
          )
        },
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
          NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('development'),
        },
      }),
      new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
      // ,
      // new UglifyJSPlugin(),
    ],
  };
```

Could it be due to the fact that I commented out some things in webpack.config: `sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,` under options and `extractTextPluginOptions`?

I commented them out bc I was getting errors during setup and was not 100% sure their role.  I'm still growing in my use of webpack and borrowed some config settings from another app I built using Facebook's create-react-app.

Input is welcome.  Thank you in advance!
Mike

Comment: Have you used the developer console to look at what css files are actually being generated?

Comment: Thank you Leo.  If I click on the '+' I see the unique hash of the selector but its contents are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to :

```
import './Sidebar.css'; //don't name the import
```

then use the class on your element like

```
<h3 className="other">Testing Stylesheet</h3>
```

(and as @Leo suggested, open Dev Tools and search for the css to see if it is sent to the browser)

Comment: Hi Leo, this worked but only after making change to my webpack.config file.  Thanks to a friend of mine who helped me evaluate the necessary changes there.  Thank you so much, Leo.